# Writing a simple enum in Swift 2 like I can in Java

Tags: swift, enums, case

In Java, I can create an enum that takes an integer as follows:

```
public
enum MyEnum {
    FOO(1), BAR(4), BAZ(8);

    private
    int value;

    MyEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How do I do the same in Swift (version 2.0)?  My guess was:

```
public
enum MyEnum {
    case FOO(1)
    case BAR(4)
    case BAZ(8)

    public
    let value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

but attempting to compile this gives the following errors:

```
Expected type
Expected ',' separator
Expected type
Expected ',' separator
Expected type
Expected ',' separator
Enums may not contain stored properties
```

(the first two on the line "case FOO(1)", the second two on "case BAR(4)", the third two on "case BAZ(8)" and the final error on the line "let value: Int")

How can I fix this Swift code to create an enum that is equivalent to the one in Java?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 public
  enum MyEnum: Int {
    case FOO = 1
    case BAR = 4
    case BAZ = 8
  }

  var foo = MyEnum(rawValue: 4)
  var rawValue = foo?.rawValue
```

In Swift there's no need for the constructor/getter of the underlying value. Those are included in Enum types (as `rawValue`, which is of the type your Enum inherits from)

Also, note that the constructor that takes in `rawValue` is failable (i.e.  returns an optional), as it's possible to pass in a `rawValue` that doesn't map to a `MyEnum`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as a direct translation...

```
public enum MyEnum: Int { // You need to declare the raw type
    case FOO = 1 // use "= x" rather than "(x)"
    case BAR = 4
    case BAZ = 8

    //public let value: Int // Enums may not contain stored properties
    //... but can contain computed values
    var value: Int {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }

    init?(value: Int) { // Fails if not 1, 4 or 8, hence "init?"
        //self.value = value // Now meaningless
        self.init(rawValue: value)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just skip most of it and use the built-in `Enum` init & properties...

```
public enum MyEnum: Int { // You need to declare the raw type
    case FOO = 1 // use "= x" rather than "(x)"
    case BAR = 4
    case BAZ = 8
}

let myEnum = MyEnum(rawValue: 4) // BAR
let four = myEnum?.rawValue // 4
let another = MyEnum(rawValue: 5) // nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Java example uses enum constants having integer values which are
powers of two. Therefore I *assume* that your intention is to define a
type which can represent not only those three constants but arbitrary
integers, e.g. 12 (for "BAR + BAZ"), i.e. a "bit set".

In Swift you can do that conveniently with a `struct` which conforms
to `OptionSetType`. Here is an example:

```
struct FileAccess: OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let Read    = FileAccess(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let Write   = FileAccess(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let Execute = FileAccess(rawValue: 1 << 0)
}
```

The value is stored as an `Int` (or whatever suitable type you chose
in the declaration). You can construct a value from a single
constant:

```
let a1 = FileAccess.Read
print(a1.rawValue) // 4
```

or from a combination:

```
let a2 = FileAccess([.Read, .Write])
print(a2.rawValue) // 6
```

or from an arbitrary integer:

```
let a3 = FileAccess(rawValue: 5)
print(a3.rawValue) // 5
```

(Unlike for `enum`, this does not return an optional and does not fail.)

`OptionSetType` offers a set-like interface which can be used
to create new values:

```
let r = FileAccess.Read
let w = FileAccess.Write
let rw = r.union(w)
```

or to test values:

```
if a1.contains(.Read) {
    print("readable")
}

if a2.isSupersetOf([.Read, .Write]) {
    print("read-write")
}
```